# Write to SD card Android

Tags: android, file, ioexception, android-external-storage

I want to give the users of my application the choice to save to the internal phone memory or to an SD card. If I create a `File` from the user's choice, the URI (without the file name) is something like:

Internal: content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3A

SD: content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/760E-F734%3A

However, if I try to write a file to these directories using the following code I get the error `java.io.IOException: No such file or directory` :

```
File writePath = new File("content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3A")

File file = new File(writePath, fileName);

try {
    file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("saveSurvey", "Failed to create file!" + e.getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

So the file would be written somewhere like this:

content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3A/[my file name]

I have declared the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in the manifest, so I guess it is not a permissions issue but more of an invalid path issue.

If these are not valid file paths, how would I go about writing to the SD card? Using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` always writes to the internal storage of my device ('/storage/emulated/0').

Comment: You are mixing two concepts when creating the File, you are sending a `content` URI while it expects a `file` URI, more info in https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html The path returned from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is correct, the AVD usually emulates an external storage in this path, and don't confuse SD card with external storage it can be a different source, more info in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez Thanks for the info. I understand that the 'external' storage could be either the SD card or the mountable device memory, but how do I write to the SD card as opposed to the device memory?

Answer (score 1):

`File` works only with filesystem paths, or with `file://` URIs, and you have a `content://` URI here. (In addition, to create a file from a URI you would pass that as a `Uri`, not as a string.)

Depending on what you are trying to do with the file, [`DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile?hl=en) may work for you. It is designed to provide an interface similar to `File` but built around the Storage Access Framework. You can obtain input and output streams for the file created that way and do some basic file operations.

The one thing that is a pain is anything involving standard Java libraries which expect a `File` argument, as there is no official way to get from a `content://` URI to an actual `File` instance—apart from hacks which may cease to work after the next update, or on the one device that has not been considered.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your File Path. 
Call a getAbsolutePath() function And checked writePath

```
File writePath = new File("content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3A")
if(writePath.exists() && writePath.isDirectory()) {
    //File extensions can be declared 
       File file = new File(writePath.getAbsolutePath(), fileName+ extensions);
}
```

Comment: This is the biggest nonsense i saw today.

Comment: @greenapps what does it mean?

Comment: That you won a price ;-).

Comment: Always worth having checks but it doesn't really answer my question unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You getting this error because the path is different in different devices.

Try to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` as `writePath`

Keep in mind in android 6 and above you must request permission at runtime

Comment: But as I mentioned in my post, this always writes to the device internal storage and not the SD card.